# How to update a field on menu_link_content (added using menu_item_extras module) entity from node form

Tags: 8, nodes

I have a checkbox field added to one of the menus using [Menu Item Extras](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_extras) module. By default, the checkbox is checked and works as expected when I create a menu item via menu admin UI. however, when I create a menu item via node, the field doesn't get the default behavior (checkbox checked). I also checked the table (`menu_link_content__[field_name]`) and there is no entry for the menu item added via `node/add` form.

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of problems here:

1. The node form has the menu fields hardcoded. See `menu_ui_form_node_form_alter()` and `menu_ui_form_node_form_submit()` for more details.
2. Turns out the root cause of the field issue is that the `Menu Item Extras` module updates the bundle value to menu name which happens on pre_save hook of menu_link_content entity. Without menu_name as bundle, the entity wouldn't have any fields associated.

One way to solve this issue is to implement a `hook_form_node_form_alter()` hook and update the bundle details before trying to update the custom field. Here is the code:

**1. mymodule/mymodule.module**

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter() for \Drupal\node\NodeForm.
 */
function mymodule_form_node_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  foreach (array_keys($form['actions']) as $action) {
    if ($action != 'preview' && isset($form['actions'][$action]['#type']) && $form['actions'][$action]['#type'] === 'submit') {
      $form['actions'][$action]['#submit'][] = [
        \Drupal::service('mymodule.menu_link_content_helper'),
        'nodeSubmit',
      ];
    }
  }
}
```

**2. mymodule/src/MenuLinkContentService.php**

```php
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Services;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\menu_link_content\Entity\MenuLinkContent;

/**
 * Class MenuLinkContentService
 *
 * @package Drupal\mymodule\Service
 */
class MenuLinkContentService  {

  /**
   * Entity type manager.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface
   */
  protected $entityTypeManager;

  /**
   * MenuLinkContentHelper constructor.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface $entityTypeManager
   *   Entity type manager.
   */
  public function __construct(EntityTypeManagerInterface $entityTypeManager) {
    $this->entityTypeManager = $entityTypeManager;
  }

  /**
   * Form submission handler for menu item field on the node form.
   *
   * @param array $form
   *   Form array.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
   *   Form state object.
   *
   * @throws \Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\InvalidPluginDefinitionException
   * @throws \Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException
   * @throws \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException
   */
  public function nodeSubmit(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    if (!$form_state->isValueEmpty('menu')) {
      $values = $form_state->getValue('menu');
      if (!empty($values['entity_id'])) {
        // There is no bundle by default for menu_link_content entity.
        $menu_name = 'menu_link_content';
        if (!empty($values['menu_parent'])) {
          list($menu_name) = explode(':', $values['menu_parent'], 2);
        }
        $entity = $this->nodeSaveMenuLinkContent($values['entity_id'], $menu_name);
        // If no  menu item with given bundle, load and update bundle.
        if (!$entity) {
          $entity = MenuLinkContent::load($values['entity_id']);
          $entity->set('bundle', $menu_name)->save();
          $this->nodeSaveMenuLinkContent($entity->id(), $menu_name);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Updates additional field on menu link content entity.
   *
   * @param int $entity_id
   *   Entity ID.
   * @param string $menu_name
   *   Menu name.
   *
   * @return \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface|mixed|null
   *   An Entity. NULL, if no entity with given ID and bundle found.
   *
   * @throws \Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\InvalidPluginDefinitionException
   * @throws \Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException
   * @throws \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException
   */
  protected function nodeSaveMenuLinkContent($entity_id, $menu_name) {
    $storage = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('menu_link_content');
    // Using loadByProperties() as loading without bundle wouldn't bring the
    // custom field.
    $entities = $storage->loadByProperties([
      'bundle' => $menu_name,
      'id' => $entity_id,
    ]);
    $entity = reset($entities);
    if ($entity) {
      $entity->set('field_searchable', TRUE);
      $entity->save();
      return $entity;
    }
    else {
      return NULL;
    }
  }

}
```

Note: my checkbox field is `field_searchable`.